# Store JTextField text into array and sum - Java

Tags: java, arrays, jtextfield

I want to somehow store the text from JTextField into array and then sum it.

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //fldi is the JTextField I want to get text from
    int ii = Integer.parseInt(fldi.getText());
  }
});
```

What should I do next? how can I split text from there, for example if user input is "256" I think it should be stored in array like "2", "5", "6".

EDIT:
So after Jake Miller's help I've got:

```
String input = fldi.getText();
            int sum = 0; 

            int[] values = new int[input.length()];
            for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            int number;
            if(input.substring(i, i+1).equals("-")) {
                number = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+2));
            } else {
                number = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+1));
            }
            values[i] = number;         
                sum = sum + values[i];
            }

            fldwo.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
```

But when I try it for negative numbers like "-2" and "-1" values array stores 4 values "-2", "2", "-1", "1" and the sum at the end is 0, but it should be -3.

Comment: Need more specifics. Are the numbers always single digit? etc.

Comment: no they can have any length

Comment: Don't parse it right away. Store the input into a String, use a loop to use .substring() to go through each character in the String, and parse each individual number and store into an int array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse it right away. Store the input into a String, use a loop to use .substring() to go through each character in the String, and parse each individual number and store into an int array.

```
String input = fldi.getText();
int[] values = new int[input.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    values[i] = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+1));
}
```

If they input 256, then the array will have 3 values: 2, 5, and 6

**EDIT**

For negative numbers, you'll need to have a check for the character "-" as it indicates a negative number. Then, you'll use `substring(i, i+2)` to take two characters as opposed to one (the - and the number itself). You also don't need the array. You can simply add each number you parse to the sum directly. You also should use a while loop and increment i on your own. If you find a negative number, you're using 2 characters, which means you need to increment i by two instead of 1.:

```
    int sum = 0;
    int i   = 0;
    while(i < input.length()) {
        int number;
        if(input.substring(i, i+1).equals("-")) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+2));
            i += 2;
        } else {
            number = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+1));
            i++;
        }
        sum += number;
    }
```

An example:

A user inputs `125-35`. The first three characters will NOT be equal to "-", therefore they'll simply be parsed and stored into the values array. Once you reach the 4th character (3rd index), the character will be a "-", so the if statement will cause number to be equal to -3 as the substring now returns two characters as opposed to one.

Comment: no you should parse like this: Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+1));

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter Sorry. Sent that answer on mobile so accidentally left that part out. Updated

Comment: And also how can I get it to work for negative numbers too?

Comment: You'll need to have an if statement to check for a dash (-) to indicate a negative number. If there's a dash, use 'substring(i, i+2)' in order to have the dash and the number parsed together.

Comment: Can you give me a code for that? it seems that I can't get it to work.

Comment: Ok, but if the input is -2 and -1 it will store 2 and 1 too into values[i] and as I sum the numbers at the end I will always get 0. Any ideas?

Comment: @wolverine961 The code I posted should store -2 and -1, not 2 and 1. Look at the code under the edit. I tested it and it works. Check the edit again.

Comment: yes it stores -2 and -1 too. if the input is -2 and -1 the length of values is 4.

Comment: and that 4 values are -2,2,-1,1

Comment: no as I said at the end I sum all of the numbers and for the above case the sum will be 0 not -1 as it shoul be.

Comment: @wolverine961 Can you edit your main post describing your problem in better detail? Execute the code, show your input, what the program outputs (the sum), and what you're expecting to give me a better idea as to what you're asking.

Comment: @wolverine961 Sorry, I made a mistake. Check the updated edit.